# AWS CLI to get list of instance from

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

How can I get list of all Instances running under multiple Accounts by using Aws CLI

I have my profile configured, need assistance with looping, assume roles and than write output in a file

Cheers

Comment: What did you try? And what did it do?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you've already configured one AWS profile for each AWS account and those AWS profiles permit to assume a role having the `ec2:DescribeInstances` action (this is typically configured inside the `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files).

The following script (`list-instances.sh`) could be written.

**Default AWS region version**

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_PROFILES=()
AWS_PROFILES[0]=profile_for_account_1
AWS_PROFILES[1]=profile_for_account_2
AWS_PROFILES[2]=profile_for_account_3

for AWS_PROFILE in ${AWS_PROFILES[*]}
do
    echo "== Profile '${AWS_PROFILE}' =="
    aws ec2 describe-instances --profile "${AWS_PROFILE}" --filters Name=instance-state-code,Values=16 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId'
done
```

**Multi-regions version**

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_PROFILES=()
AWS_PROFILES[0]=profile_for_account_1
AWS_PROFILES[1]=profile_for_account_2
AWS_PROFILES[2]=profile_for_account_3

for AWS_PROFILE in ${AWS_PROFILES[*]}
do
    for AWS_REGION in $(aws ec2 describe-regions | jq -r '.Regions[].RegionName')
    do
        echo "== profile: ${AWS_PROFILE}, region: ${AWS_REGION}"
        aws ec2 describe-instances --profile "${AWS_PROFILE}" --region "${AWS_REGION}" --filters Name=instance-state-code,Values=16 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId'
    done
done
```

- You must have the `jq` command to parse the JSON output (see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) ;
- If you want more than only the EC2 instance identifiers feel free to update the jq expression ;
- The `--filters` returns only EC2 instances in the `running`, be careful because it will not list instances in `pending`, `shutting-down` or `stopping` states (see the `instance-state-code` filter documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html) ;
- You can redirect the output to a file with `./list-instances.sh > instance-identifiers.txt`. Then simply use `cat instance-identifiers.txt | grep -v "==" | cat` to loop again (here the `cat` command apply on each EC2 instance identifier, you can replace it by another command).

Hope this helps.

Baptiste

Comment: Suggested addition:  I believe the account profiles must be put in the "credentials" file as outlined here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

Comment: I tested this script and it works, but it does not take into account multiple regions.  An enhanced version would also iterate all regions in use.

Comment: Thanks @vjones, I updated the response to explain the profiles are configured both in the "credentials" and "config" files. Also I added a multi-regions version. Do you think its good now ? Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, it seems to address the original question quite well. I prefer to filter on both running and stopped instances using aws ec2 describe-instances --profile "${AWS_PROFILE}" --region "${AWS_REGION}" --filters Name=instance-state-code,Va
lues=16,80 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId'